# Can't bind a ViewModel ObservableCollection to listview

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I've been trying to bind an ObservableCollection from the ViewModel to my listview but nothing shows up in the list view not even blank cells

**I want to load the items in my database to the listview**

The Model:

```
public class Note
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

The View Model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Boom { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddNoteIconCommand { get; private set; }
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _db;
    private ObservableCollection<Note> _notes;
    public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes
    {
        get { return _notes; }
        set
        {
            if (_notes == value)
                return;

            _notes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private INavigation Navigation;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigation Navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = Navigation;
        AddNoteIconCommand = new Command(AddNewNote);
        PrepareDatabase();
        Boom = "Hello";
    }

    private async void PrepareDatabase()
    {
        _db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
        var _databasenotes = await _db.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();
        _notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>(_databasenotes);
    }

    private async void AddNewNote()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewNotePage());
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

MainPage Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoteTaker"
         x:Class="NoteTaker.MainPage"
         Padding="10">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="Plus.png" Command="{Binding AddNoteIconCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

<StackLayout>
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Notes, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding Body}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
<Entry Text = "{Binding Boom}" />
</StackLayout>
```

MainPage Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel(Navigation);
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
}
```

Where is the problem here ?
Note: I've made sure through debugging that my observable collection is populated with the database objects

Comment: Try calling InitializeComponent first

Comment: I've tried, didn't work though

Comment: try creating the VM before you assign it to the BindingContext

Comment: What about if you set the VM in the  `<DataContext>` rather than using code behind?

Comment: You should not instanciate a new `ObservableCollection` after binding. When adding items clear the collection and iterate through it to add items one by one. By creating a new instance it will lose the ability to notify the UI, you will have to set the binding again.

Comment: @Gerlad How do you recommend me to fix that ?

Comment: @Jason didn't work bro.

Comment: @MickyD I need to do it from the code behind because i need to pass an argument, but i can assure you that it's binded because I've a plus button which runs a command from the view model and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Managed to fix the bug, the problem was with the line "new ObservableCollection" and i fixed that by adding the items manually through a foreach loop to the observable collection. And That Solved the problem and worked like a charm !

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand AddNoteIconCommand { get; private set; }
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _db;
    private ObservableCollection<Note> _notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>();
    public ObservableCollection<Note> Notes            
    {
        get { return _notes; }
        set
        {
            if (_notes == value)
                return;

            _notes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private INavigation Navigation;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigation Navigation)
    {
        this.Navigation = Navigation;
        AddNoteIconCommand = new Command(AddNewNote);
        PrepareDatabase();

    }

    private async void PrepareDatabase()
    {
        _db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>().GetConnection();
        var _databasenotes = await _db.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();
        FillObservable(_databasenotes);
    }

    private async void AddNewNote()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewNotePage());
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void FillObservable(List<Note> _dbnotes)
    {
        foreach (var note in _dbnotes)
        {
            _notes.Add(note);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the view that `MainPageViewModel.Notes` is changed.

Your code `Notes = new ObservableCollection<Note>(_notes);` did not send any notification to the view, so the view was not updated. You may make `MainPageViewModel` a [`BindableObject`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/) and call `OnPropertyChanged` to notify the view that there are new notes.

As a side note, you should manage database connection in model instead of view model to follow MVVM pattern.

Comment: I've edited my ViewModel code and implemented the OnPropertyChanged But Still doesn't work and the list shows blank

Comment: @Omar It seems that `OnPropertyChanged()` was not called with correct `propertyName`, it should be `"Notes"` instead of `null`. Or you may use `[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]` attribute to get the name automatically.

Comment: I've tryed typing Notes and after that I've added the CallerMemberName attribute but still the list still to be empty